# link_to to display a data set with an erb template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We would like to provide a link in a view to display with a template `search_result.html.erb` and data set stored in `@data` (`@data` is used in search_result.html.erb) in a new window. We are thinking something like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Search Result', @data, :target => '_blank' do %>
   <%=render 'search_result' %>
<% end %>
```

Is this something working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. You need a controller to do that. For example,

```
# data_controller.rb
class DataController < ApplicationController
  def search
    # do something with @data here
  end
end
```

You also need to define this route in `routes.rb`

```
# routes.rb
get 'search' => 'data#search'
```

Now you can display the link in view

```
<%= link_to 'Search Result', search_path, :target => '_blank' %>
```

Comment: Since there is a `@data` we want to skip the controller. Is it possible?

Comment: If you want to render a view with the same route, it is possible. But with a different route, let a controller do this.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to define a route in routes.rb pointing to an action in a controller like:

```
get 'search_result' => 'YourController#YourAction'
```

In your view, add the link as below:

```
<%= link_to 'Search Result', search_result_path(:data => @data), :target => '_blank' %>
```

In your action, you can get your `@data` with:

```
@data = params[:data]
```